# How to fix anchor issue in Codepen : "Bad path /boomboom/v2

Tags: html, css, codepen

I want to create an anchor to navigate into my webpage. I correctly seted my Performances where "Performances" is supposed to drive to :Performances.

When im clicking the link provided, i have an error : /boomboom/v2/anchor1, though i think my code is correct. It's an exercise to enter web developer studies, so im quite embarassed ! Im worcking on "Codepen website"

link to my codepen : https://codepen.io/Peyo5202/pen/zYOrzMZ?editors=1000#0

- Performances

...
 Performances

I exept the output of clicking on "performance" to drive me down to my anchor1, but instead i have "/boomboom/v2/anchor1". How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to link to an ID on the page, you need to use the `#` selector in your link

this html will correctly link to that section when you click Performances:

```
<li><a href="#anchor1">Performances</a></li>
```

Comment: Thank you so much !